# Подключение к бд mysql через консоль

Tags: mysql, консоль

Для удалённого компьютера создал пользователя типа 'user'@'mypc' как мне теперь к нему подключиться на сервере?

С удалённого ПК подключаюсь так:

```
mysql -h serverSQL -u user -p
```

Как подключиться от имени этого пользователя на сервере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не сможете подключиться локально из под учетной записи удаленного пользователя 'user'@'mypc', если только вместо mypc вы не указали любой хост  'user'@'%'. Если mypc - это адрес удаленного сервера, сервер MySQL будет ждать обращений именно с него.

Для локального входа из под пользователя user, вам потребуется локальная учетная запись 'user'@'localhost' или 'user'@'127.0.0.1', тогда вы сможете входить так

```
mysql -u user -p
```

или просто по команде `mysql`, если пропишите в .my.cnf в секции `[client]` имя пользователя и его пароль

```
[client]
user=user
password=pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите подключиться от имени текущего пользователя, под которым работаете в системе, то просто не указывайте параметр `-u`

```
mysql -h host.sql.ru -p12345
```

При попытке подключения будет автоматически подставлено имя текущего пользователя системы.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы находитесь непосредственно на сервере либо через ssh либо через telnet или другой вариант. Вам достаточно будет выполнить:

```
mysql -u user -p
```

После чего ввести пароль пользователя.

Главное что бы у пользователя user  на сервере mysql был разрешён доступ не только с удаленного хоста aka ваш комп но и доступ с localhost или вообще с любого хоста, а так же что бы сервер MySql был настроен на прослушку как внешнего интерфейса так и localhost.